# c++ - working with large data set - algorithm results match for 1k entries test but fail at 1million entries test - same algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, file, sorting

**What the problem is:**
I am parsing a file which can be a 1k row file or a 1million row file. My output data for the 1k file matches the expected result 1:1 but my 1million lines file gives me incorrect results.

**What could be wrong with my algorithm to produce such weird results?**

**Algorithm explanation**

What this is supposed to return is the top 10 results in ascending order from a set of say 1million values ( values which are used for some computation to compute a result that determines score )

**Here is my algorithm for performing the calculations.**

```
std::vector<ResultType> circularSubvectorMatch(const unsigned int vector_size, std::vector<float>* searchVector, VectorsMap* circularVector, const unsigned int n, unsigned int begin_index, unsigned int end_index, unsigned int shm_start, unsigned int shm_end, float* shm, const bool is_test){
    unsigned int i, j, row_index;
    const unsigned int item_size = (*circularVector).size();
    //vector for the returned top N results;
    std::vector<ResultType> results;
    results.reserve(n);
    ResultType one;
    std::vector<float> tmp;
    float x, y, dist, dist_tmp;
    int offset;

    //iterate over the whole set of vectors parsed from the file.
    for (row_index=begin_index; row_index < end_index; row_index++) {
        //get a copy of the the vector at position row_index and remove it
        tmp = (*circularVector).at(row_index);
        //get the first and second key and erase them
        x = tmp.at(0);
        tmp.erase(tmp.begin());
        y = tmp.at(0);
        tmp.erase(tmp.begin());

        //run through every vector point at steps of 5
        for(i=0; i<VECTOR_COUNT; i+=5){
            dist = 0;
            offset = i;
            dist_tmp = 0;
            //loop through the vector size(9,11,17,29)
            for(j=0; j<vector_size; j++){
                dist_tmp = fabs((*searchVector).at(j) - tmp.at((j+i)%360));
                dist += dist_tmp;
            }

            //put the result into the structure

            one.x = x;
            one.y = y;
            one.offset = i;
            one.dist = dist;

            //Begins min heap process
            if(results.size() < 10){
                results.push_back(one);
            }
            // Compare it to the max element in the heap 
            else if (one < results.front()) {
                 // Add the new element to the vector
                 results.push_back(one);
                 // Move the existing minimum to the back and "re-heapify" the rest
                 std::pop_heap(results.begin(), results.end());
                 // Remove the last element from the vector
                 results.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
    //sort to fix the min heap operations
    std::sort(results.begin(), results.end());
    results.resize(n);
    int count = 0;

    //if we are not running a test, save to memory
    if(!is_test){
        for(i=shm_start; i<shm_end; i++){
            shm[i] = results.at(count).x;
            shm[i+1] = results.at(count).y;
            shm[i+2] = results.at(count).offset;
            shm[i+3] = results.at(count).dist;
            count++;
            i+=3;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a priority queue. After each calculation for a row, put the value into the queue. If the size of the queue is 11, then remove the smallest value from the queue. When all rows are processed just remove the 10 values in the queue.

Comment: that is pretty much what I am using. It turned out that the provided results were incorrect and my algorithm is correct.